# Altering device temperature of Galaxy S4

Tags: android, kernel, galaxy

I want to write an Android APP for doing RAM test on galaxy s4 device. And I want them to be done in certain temperature or when the temperature is gradually increasing/decreasing.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this temperature change will be greatly helpful. I would like to know, is there any chance of achieving the same either through the s4 device functionalities, or by using the kernel or Android?

I tried with some intense resource using application, but still I am not able to achieve it.

Comment: An oven, or a refrigerator maybe?

Comment: Direct sunlight? (on a hot day)

Answer (score 2):

Yes-  use an external heating device.  There's no way to control the heat of the device via API.  Instead go out and buy a heater and put the phone on top of it.  If you want accurate control, there's ovens used in testing electronics you can buy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gabe Sechan. What about "over clocking", will that help me in any way for altering the temperature?

Comment: Overclocking will raise the temperature, but its not really something that's predictable.  It also will cause the processor itself to malfunction as it goes faster/gets hotter, so it isn't really a good way of testing ram.  Also, modern chips will have temperature throttling built in that will automatically underclock if it gets too hot.  So it will only work for a small range of values.

Comment: And running any other application in the background for altering the temperature is also fine, will that be achievable, any suggestions? Thanks